# R function writing - getting error: NaNs producedError in tsort[U + 1]only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r

I am creating an R function that calculates a bootstrapped bias corrected and accelerated interval, (not using any pre-installed packages) My code seems to be working but am struggling actually writing the code for the lower and upper limits of the interval. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
BCa <- function(stat,X,k,level=0.95,...){

if(!is.numeric(k)||k<=0){
    stop("The number of bootstrap resamples 'k' must be a numeric value greater than 0")
}

  t.star <- stat(X,...)
  t.k <- rep(NA,k)

   for(i in 1:k){
    Xi <- sample(X,replace=TRUE)
    t.k[i] <- stat(Xi,...)
   }

  z0 <- qnorm(mean(t.k<t.star))

  n <- length(X)
  t.minus.j <- rep(NA,n)
  for(j in 1:n){
    Xj <- X[-j]
     t.minus.j[j]<- stat(Xj,...)
  }

  t.bar.minus <- mean(t.minus.j)
  t.diff <- t.bar.minus - t.minus.j
  a <- ((sum(t.diff^3))/(6*(t.diff^2)^3/2))  
  alpha <- 1-level
  tsort <- sort(t.k, decreasing = FALSE)

  L <- pnorm(z0 + ((z0+qnorm(alpha/2))/((1-a)*z0+qnorm(alpha/2))))

  U <- qnorm(z0 + ((z0+qnorm(alpha/2))/((1-a)*z0+qnorm(alpha/2))))

  if(!is.integer(L)){
 L <- floor(L*(k+1))
  }
  if(!is.integer(U)){
 U <- ceiling(U*(k+1))
  }

  lower.limit <- tsort[L]
  upper.limit <- tsort[U+1]

  return(list(t.star=t.star,ci=c(lower.limit,upper.limit)))
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do looking at the code above. Can you show what would be your input to the function and corresponding expected output ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah, The input would look like this: BCa(stat=mean,X=Nile,k=9999,level=0.95), using for example, the Nile data from R. The out put should give the BCa interval for this data giving the upper/lower limits - but this is where I am struggling.